# Does iOS log emergency (911/999/112) calls?

Tags: iphone

Obviously this isn't something I can test and confirm myself, and I'm unable to find any confirmation either way elsewhere. My question is simple:

After making an emergency call on an iOS device, is the call logged within the phone history?

(I realise emergency calls are nearly always fully logged elsewhere, but I'm only interested at the device level)

Comment: Do you mean in "Recent Calls", or are you talking about some other kind of logging? Of course they show up in Recent Calls, they are after all, calls.

Answer (score 2):

Mine does.

(Pardon the image quality... I had to take a picture of one smartphone's call log with another, very old smartphone.)

[image]

Comment: But was the call made from a locked phone? That might make a difference.